# LDAP Integration with CAS + Spring

Tags: java, spring, ldap, cas

I am integrating LDAP with CAS. The exception that comes is correct because i have not specified the credentials properly. So the below exception is expected.

But due to this the war is also not deployed. Which is not correct.

So what i want is that for what ever reason, ldap connection is not established, at least the war should face any problem in deployment and the application should be accessible.

Exception can later be thrown when a user tries to login using ldap credentials.

Can anyone suggest on this. How can this be achieved?

Please find below stack trace.

```
2015-03-10 23:17:21,929 WARN [org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool] - <unable to create available connection>
2015-03-10 23:17:22,142 ERROR [org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool] - <unable to connect to the ldap>
[org.ldaptive.LdapException@615736136::resultCode=INVALID_CREDENTIALS, matchedDn=null, responseControls=null, referralURLs=null, messageId=-1, providerException=javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, v1771^@]]
        at org.ldaptive.provider.ProviderUtils.throwOperationException(ProviderUtils.java:77)
        at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnection.processNamingException(JndiConnection.java:756)
        at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnection.simpleBind(JndiConnection.java:301)
        at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnection.bind(JndiConnection.java:227)
        at org.ldaptive.BindOperation.invoke(BindOperation.java:42)
        at org.ldaptive.BindOperation.invoke(BindOperation.java:22)
        at org.ldaptive.AbstractOperation.execute(AbstractOperation.java:142)
        at org.ldaptive.BindConnectionInitializer.initialize(BindConnectionInitializer.java:170)
        at org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory$DefaultConnection.open(DefaultConnectionFactory.java:297)
        at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.createConnection(AbstractConnectionPool.java:432)
        at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.createAvailableConnection(AbstractConnectionPool.java:453)
        at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.grow(AbstractConnectionPool.java:337)
        at org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool.initialize(AbstractConnectionPool.java:249)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:375)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:623)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, v1771^@]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.reconnect(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.reconnect(Unknown Source)
        at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnection.simpleBind(JndiConnection.java:287)
        ... 113 more
```

My deployerConfigContext is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>

                <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
                <entry key-ref="jdbcAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="usernameCredentialPrincipalResolver" />
                <entry key-ref="atnLdapAuthenticationHandler" value="#{null}" />

            </map>
        </constructor-arg>

        <property name="authenticationPolicy">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AnyAuthenticationPolicy" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Required for proxy ticket mechanism. -->
    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationHandler"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler"
          p:httpClient-ref="httpClient" />


    <bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler">
        <property name="users">
            <map>
                <entry key="casuser" value="Mellon"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Required for proxy ticket mechanism -->
    <bean id="proxyPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.BasicPrincipalResolver" />

    <bean id="primaryPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver" >
        <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao"
            p:backingMap-ref="attrRepoBackingMap" />

    <util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
        <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
        <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" /> 
        <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
    </util:map>


    <bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl"
            p:registeredServices-ref="registeredServicesList" />

    <util:list id="registeredServicesList">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService"
              p:id="0" p:name="HTTP and IMAP" p:description="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols"
              p:serviceId="^(https?|imaps?)://.*" p:evaluationOrder="10000001" />

    </util:list>

    <bean id="auditTrailManager" class="com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager" />

    <bean id="healthCheckMonitor" class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.HealthCheckMonitor" p:monitors-ref="monitorsList" />

    <!-- LDAP CHanges start -->
<!--     <bean id="ldapPrincipalResolver" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver"></bean> -->
    <bean id="atnLdapAuthenticationHandler" class="com.airtight.cas.authentication.ATNLdapAuthenticationHandler" p:principalIdAttribute="cn"
        c:authenticator-ref="authenticator">
        <property name="principalAttributeMap">
            <map>
            <!--
               | This map provides a simple attribute resolution mechanism.
               | Keys are LDAP attribute names, values are CAS attribute names.
               | Use this facility instead of a PrincipalResolver if LDAP is
               | the only attribute source.
               -->
                <entry key="cn" value="cn" />
                <entry key="mail" value="mail" />
                <entry key="givenName" value="givenName" />
                <entry key="sn" value="sn" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler" p:principalIdAttribute="cn"
        c:authenticator-ref="authenticator">
        <property name="principalAttributeMap">
            <map>

               | This map provides a simple attribute resolution mechanism.
               | Keys are LDAP attribute names, values are CAS attribute names.
               | Use this facility instead of a PrincipalResolver if LDAP is
               | the only attribute source.

                <entry key="cn" value="cn" />
                <entry key="mail" value="mail" />
                <entry key="givenName" value="givenName" />
                <entry key="sn" value="sn" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="authenticator" class="org.ldaptive.auth.Authenticator" c:resolver-ref="dnResolver" c:handler-ref="authHandler" />
<!--     <bean id="dnResolver" class="org.ldaptive.auth.FormatDnResolver" c:format="%s@${ldap.domain}" /> -->
    <bean id="dnResolver" class="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledSearchDnResolver" p:baseDn="${ldap.baseDn}" p:subtreeSearch="true" p:allowMultipleDns="false"
        p:connectionFactory-ref="searchPooledLdapConnectionFactory" p:userFilter="${ldap.authn.searchFilter}" />
    <bean id="searchPooledLdapConnectionFactory" class="org.ldaptive.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" p:connectionPool-ref="searchConnectionPool" />
    <bean id="searchConnectionPool" parent="abstractConnectionPool" p:connectionFactory-ref="searchConnectionFactory" />
    <bean id="searchConnectionFactory" class="org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory" p:connectionConfig-ref="searchConnectionConfig" />
    <bean id="searchConnectionConfig" parent="abstractConnectionConfig" p:connectionInitializer-ref="bindConnectionInitializer" />
    <bean id="bindConnectionInitializer" class="org.ldaptive.BindConnectionInitializer" p:bindDn="${ldap.managerDn}">
        <property name="bindCredential">
            <bean class="org.ldaptive.Credential" c:password="${ldap.managerPassword}" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="abstractConnectionPool" abstract="true" class="org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool" init-method="initialize" p:poolConfig-ref="ldapPoolConfig"
        p:blockWaitTime="${ldap.pool.blockWaitTime}" p:validator-ref="searchValidator" p:pruneStrategy-ref="pruneStrategy" p:failFastInitialize="false" />
    <bean id="abstractConnectionConfig" abstract="true" class="org.ldaptive.ConnectionConfig" p:ldapUrl="${ldap.url}"
        p:connectTimeout="${ldap.connectTimeout}" p:useStartTLS="${ldap.useStartTLS}" p:sslConfig-ref="sslConfig" />
    <bean id="ldapPoolConfig" class="org.ldaptive.pool.PoolConfig" p:minPoolSize="${ldap.pool.minSize}" p:maxPoolSize="${ldap.pool.maxSize}"
        p:validateOnCheckOut="${ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout}" p:validatePeriodically="${ldap.pool.validatePeriodically}" p:validatePeriod="${ldap.pool.validatePeriod}" />
    <bean id="sslConfig" class="org.ldaptive.ssl.SslConfig">
        <property name="credentialConfig">
            <bean class="org.ldaptive.ssl.X509CredentialConfig" p:trustCertificates="${ldap.trustedCert}" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="pruneStrategy" class="org.ldaptive.pool.IdlePruneStrategy" p:prunePeriod="${ldap.pool.prunePeriod}" p:idleTime="${ldap.pool.idleTime}" />
    <bean id="searchValidator" class="org.ldaptive.pool.SearchValidator" />
    <bean id="authHandler" class="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledBindAuthenticationHandler" p:connectionFactory-ref="bindPooledLdapConnectionFactory" />
    <bean id="bindPooledLdapConnectionFactory" class="org.ldaptive.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" p:connectionPool-ref="bindConnectionPool" />
    <bean id="bindConnectionPool" parent="abstractConnectionPool" p:connectionFactory-ref="bindConnectionFactory" />
    <bean id="bindConnectionFactory" class="org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory" p:connectionConfig-ref="bindConnectionConfig" />
    <bean id="bindConnectionConfig" parent="abstractConnectionConfig" />
    <!-- LDAP CHanges end -->

    <util:list id="monitorsList">
      <bean class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.MemoryMonitor" p:freeMemoryWarnThreshold="10" />

      <bean class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.SessionMonitor"
          p:ticketRegistry-ref="ticketRegistry"
          p:serviceTicketCountWarnThreshold="5000"
          p:sessionCountWarnThreshold="100000" />
    </util:list>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set failFastInitialize="false" which should give you the desired behavior. It's likely some other configuration issue that is causing the war not to deploy. Disable the ldaptive logs and see if anything else catches your eye.

Comment: To be precise failFastInitialize will be add in 

<bean id="abstractConnectionPool" abstract="true" class="org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool" init-method="initialize" p:poolConfig-ref="ldapPoolConfig"
        p:blockWaitTime="${ldap.pool.blockWaitTime}" p:validator-ref="searchValidator" p:pruneStrategy-ref="pruneStrategy" p:failFastInitialize="false" />